# readOrders and fill ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, readfile

I'm trying to read a data file like this:

```
N 1000.0 NY              
R 2000.0 CA 0.09            
R 500.0 GA 0.07           
N 2000.0 WY             
O 3000.0 Japan 0.11 20.0            
N 555.50 CA            
O 3300.0 Ecuador 0.03 30.0          
R 600.0 NC 0.06
```

and use it to fill an arrayList

My program consists of a abstract class and three classes to implement it:

#### 1. NonProfitOrder

```
public class NonProfitOrder extends Order {

public NonProfitOrder(double price, String location) {
    super(price, location);
}
public double calculateBill() {
    return getPrice();
}
public String printOrder(String format){
    String Long = "Non-Profit Order" + "\nLocation: " + getLocation() +  "\nTotal Price: " + getPrice();
    String Short = "Non-Profit Order-Location: " + getLocation() + ", " + "Total Price: " + getPrice();
    if (format.equals("Long")){
        return Long;
    }
    else{
        return Short;
    }
}
}
```

#### 2. RegularOrder

```
public class RegularOrder extends Order {
double taxRate;

public RegularOrder(double price, String location, double taxRate) {
    super(price, location);
    this.taxRate = taxRate;
}
private double calcTax() {
    double tax;
    tax = getPrice() * taxRate;
    return tax;
}
public double calculateBill() {
    double bill;
    bill = price + calcTax();
    return bill;
}
public String printOrder(String format){
    String Long = "Regular Order" + "\nLocation: " + getLocation() +  "\nPrice: " + getPrice() + 
            "\nTax: " + calcTax() + "\nTotal Price: " + calculateBill();
    String Short = "Regular Order-Location: " + getLocation() + ", " + "Total Price: " + calculateBill();
    if (format.equals("Long")){
        return Long;
    }
    else{
        return Short;
    }
}
}
```

and another very similar to `RegularOrder`

My problem comes in my main. I have to use a method `readOrders(fileName:string):ArrayList<Order>`

```
public static ArrayList<Order> readOrders (String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String type;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("orders.txt"));
    ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    while (s.hasNext()){
        type = s.nextLine();
    }
    switch(type) {
        case 1: type = NonProfitOrder();
            break;
        case 2: type = RegularOrder();
            break;
        case 3: type = OverseasOrder();
    return orders;
}
```

}

I can't figure out how to do this properly as it still says

> readOrders can't be resolved to a type.

As well as other issues with the first `readOrders`.

I updated my code with somewhat of a switch state, that doesn't work of. Instead of case 1,2,3 should I be using N,O,R or how would I refer to each type of order? Also I'm having "type mismatch" error but I'm having trouble fixing it.

Comment: `ArrayList<Order> orders2 = new readOrders("orders.txt");` this sentence makes no sense.. I agree with your compiler

Comment: Do you just need to skip the `new`? If your function returns the array list, that will work

Comment: Where is the `readOrders` method??

Comment: I deleted the 'new' I put that there by mistake. The readOrders method is my problem I'm not sure how to write it. My UML has it as readOrders(fileName:string):ArrayList<Order>. However, when I write it such as "public ArrayList<Orders> readOrders(String fileName)"   I get 'Illegal modifier for parameter readOrders; only final is permitted' and can't seem to fix it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from data file to fill ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753129/reading-from-data-file-to-fill-arraylist) it's similar to your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly initialising your ArrayList and read orders method. This code here is not correct, the method ends after the `;` and does nothing and the rest is invalid

```
ArrayList<Order> readOrders (String fileName); {
    ArrayList<Order> orders2 = new readOrders("orders.txt");
}
```

What you are needing to do is create a method `readOrder` like the following [See this post on how to read in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist). Except in your case you will need to do more work in the loop to create the `Order` object

```
public static ArrayList<Order> readOrders (String fileName){
     ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
     //Read in lines from your file
     //Decide which type of order it is and create it
     //Add it to the list
     //Repeat until end of file
     return orders
}
```

Then in your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<Order> loadedOrders = readOrders("orders.txt");
     //... rest of your code
}
```

### ADDITIONAL EDIT

To insert them into the list do something like this

```
char firstChar =  //Read in the first character of the line from the file
Order anOrder;
switch(firstChar)
{
    case 'N':
       anOrder = new NonProfitOrder();  //adding arguments to construtor as needed
       break;
    case 'R':
       anOrder = new RegularOrder();
       break;
    default:
       anOrder = new Order();
       break;
 }
 loadedOrders.add(anOrder);
```

Then when reading, depending on what you need to do with the order you will might need to use `instanceof` and cast. However you can avoid this if in the base class you have the methods declared and only override them in the sub classes, then when you read from the List, the method is looked for in the subclass first, if its not found then is looked for in the base class, then if its not in the base class obviously you will get an error. This where having an abstract base class is useful and means you can avoid doing this

```
Order ord = orders.get(anIndex)

if(ord instanceof NonProfitOrder)
    ((NonProfitOrder)ord).aNonprofitOrderSpecificMethod()
else if (ord instanceof RegularOrder())
    ((RegularOrder)ord).aRegularOrderSpecificMethod();
//.....
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, except one question, how would I go about distinguishing between the different types?

Comment: At a guess: It appears that the first Letter in the data file relates what type of order it is

Comment: Yes it does, so I would need an if statement for all three types?

Comment: Yes, or since it is a single character you could use a `switch`

Comment: Ok I'm having trouble using the switch to refer to each time. Do I need a variable to refer to each type or instance of?

Comment: Not sure what your having trouble with but see my edit, this might help you.